# Do self-directed "not nice" statements violate "be nice" policy?

Tags: discussion, be-nice-policy

Are statements which would ordinarily considered to be in violation of ["be nice" policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) considered OK if they are explicitly directed at oneself (e.g. calling yourself not-nice epithets, or your own post "stupid"/"whiny"?

E.g.:

- You are ignorant and your question is dumb: **clearly NOT NICE**
- I'm ignorant and my last question was dumb: **????**

Answer (score 4):

From the policy:

> Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").

So everything should go about the post and not the person asking it. Does it really matter if the policy allows name-calling yourself? Won't that comment just be not useful at all? Why should it stay anyways?

Answer (score 3):

I think it comes down to two main things: language and intent.

If the language is in and of itself offensive then yes it goes against "be nice". Using profanity or clearly derogatory terms, for example, clearly goes against the policy, regardless of who they are directed against.

If the language itself is pretty tame then it's more about intent. If the statement is explicitly and clearly aimed at yourself then you're less likely to offend anyone. Self deprecation is usually seen as being said with at least a bit of sarcasm or humour. At the very least it's unlikely to be seen with any malicious intent, but context is important.

It just comes down to common sense. If it's likely to cause offence—don't say it.

As for your example "I'm ignorant and my last question was dumb". Without knowing the context that is *probably* OK, but it seems like a stupid thing to say regardless.